# IE7 Dropdown Menu Issue

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-7

I've got a dropdown menu setup. Works fine in Firefox / IE8 etc. But not in IE7, Ideally I would like to get this to work. The menu dissapears when I hover over it in IE7. I've tried playing about with the height but had no joy.

My code is as follows...

CSS..

```
#topNav ul {
    list-style:none outside none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#topNav ul, topnav ul ul {
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#topNav ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    padding:35px 24px;
    list-style:none outside none;
    position:relative;
}
#topNav ul li ul {
    color:#000000;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 68px;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:180px;
    z-index:1000;
    height: 200px;
}
#topNav ul .home a, #topNav ul .coffeetable a, #topNav .coffeetable a, #topNav .audio a, #topNav .graphic a {
    color:#ff9966;
}

#topNav ul .photography a, #topNav ul .video  a, #topNav ul .web a, #topNav ul .contact a {
    color: #fff;
}

#topNav ul li ul li {
    color:#FF7E00;
    display:block;
    margin:0 0 5px;
    padding:15px;
    width: 240px;
}

#topNav ul li ul li a {
    color:#000000;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
}

#topNav ul li.submenu:hover ul {
    left:0;
    visibility:visible;
}

#topNav ul li.submenu:hover ul li {
    background-color: #000;
    margin:0;
    padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

HTML...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>The Picturebook Studio Ltd.</title>
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body {behavior: url(includes/csshover.htc);} 

</style>
<![endif]-->
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Kozuka_Gothic_Pro_OpenType_400-Kozuka_Gothic_Pro_OpenType_700.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('li');
    Cufon.replace('h1');
    Cufon.replace('p');
    Cufon.replace('ol li');
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
<div id="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="The Picturebook Studio Ltd" />
</div>

<div id="content">
    <h1>Welcome to the picturebook studio limited <br />
</h1>

    <p class="whiteParagraph">We employ a team of in house professionals which include:</p>
        <ol>
            <li>photographers</li>
            <li>videographers</li>
            <li>sound engineers</li>
            <li>graphic designers</li>
            <li>web designers</li>
        </ol>

   <p>We provide the following 'unique' services :</p>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Included NAV File....

```
<div id="topNav">
    <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#" title="Home">home</a></li>
        <li class="submenu photography">
            <a href="#" title="Photography">photography</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Actors / Presenters / Headshots">Actors / Presenters Headshots</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Model / Portfolio Shoots">Model / Portfolio Shoots</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="People / Portraits">People / Portraits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Wedings / Coffee Table Books">Weddings / Coffee Table Books</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Editorial / Commercial">Editorial / Commercial</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="coffeetable"><a href="#" title="coffee table books">coffee table books</a></li>
        <li class="submenu video">
            <a href="#" title="video production">video production</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Actors / Presenters Showreels">Actors / Presenters Showreels</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Corporate">Corporate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Industrial">Industrial</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Training Education">Training Education</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Weddings">Weddings</a></li>
                </ul>                    
        </li>
        <li class="submenu audio">
            <a href="#" title="audio production">audio production</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Voice Over">Voice Over</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Music Production">Music Production</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="web"><a href="#" title="web design">web design</a></li>
        <li class="submenu graphic">
            <a href="#" title="graphic design">graphic design</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="PR">PR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Logo Design">Logo Design</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#" title="contact us">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I fix this so that the hover doesnt break? Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Threw it here: http://www.webdevout.net/test?0n seems to behave the same in IE7/8/9/Chrome/FF not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Could you paste your complete HTML file?

Comment: @Aren thats interesting, seems to flick on but when you hover over it, it definatley makes the links impossible to click as they dissapear.

Comment: @thirtydot I've set the topNav as an include file so that is all the HTML Code..

Comment: @StuBlackett: Take a look at @Aren's demo: http://www.webdevout.net/test?0n - I highly doubt it looks like that on your page. You need to post a *complete HTML file* - by that I mean include `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags, and the parent element(s) of `#topNav`. I also need to see your doctype.

Comment: Personally id do this with some javascript (jQuery?) assistance. Makes life easier than trying to rely on browser compliance to CSS Standards.

Comment: You know what @Aren. I was considering jQuery, may just looking into that. Although an conditional IE statement may fix this, I feel

Comment: @thirtydot.. I will add the full HTML to the question, Cheers

Comment: Ultimately Conditional IE Statements become a mess to manage. Managing seperate codebases for different browsers is a good way to get yourself in a mess. Your code is less discoverable, harder to read, and more prone to tedious patches and bugfix work. If you use jQuery and simpler CSS, the jQuery team takes care of the conditional browser statements. Your code can be easily written ONCE, in a nice simple file and cleanly applied & reused as you see fit.

Comment: @StuBlackett: I hate to sound tedious, but your provided code still doesn't reproduce the bug in IE7. [Here's everything you've given so far rolled into one file](http://pastebin.com/ntpYWVxL) - and it behaves the same in IE7 and IE8. **I guess the easiest thing you could do is to post a link to your live test site.** Otherwise, you need to make sure you post code which reproduces the bug in IE7. Again, sorry to sound tedious, but it's going to take someone smarter than me to solve this without a working test case. :) *(I removed some elements from your HTML, because there's no CSS for them)*

Comment: @thirtydot, Thanks for your help fella' certainly not sounding tedious. I understand that if you're not replicating the error then, you obviously cant solve it. I'm going to take a closer look at it. It may just be something in my browser, although I'm not sure what.. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case...All I can suggest is to double check to make sure your browser & document modes are definitely in IE7 mode, read up about IE7 Z-index approaches. trial and error css position types, I believe there's some glitches with IE7 to do with css display types (hidden).

clean up your CSS, I know everyone will be like "what" but sometimes you find nice fixes when you remove errors as some browsers are more sensitive & strict to things like spaces around selectors, commas etc.

If all of that doesn't work and you scale the web looking for a solution, and you find nothing. Just make an IE7 redirect (you can do this without JS), IE7 is not worth the stress unless your client & clients clients are frequent users of IE7 such as tight ass corporations who don't want to upgrade.

Hope that helps

(sorry I only looked at your code for 2 seconds)

Comment: This is really not that useful as an answer. Doesn't really address the problem, just offers generic advice.

Comment: Yes It's generic advice it will be more beneficial. You can't just solve every problem with a straight answer sometimes you need to trial and error.